# Splitting VB.NET string with infinite splits

Tags: vb.net, string, split

In VB.Net how do I split a string (numbers and letters) by each real number. For Example

1. Membership application is missing 2. Members credit score is low 3. No reported income

into

1. Membership application is missing
2. Members credit score is low
3. No reported income

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You'll get better responses if you show what you have tried, and how that failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Dim source = "1. Membership application is missing 2. Members credit score is low 3. No reported income"

    Dim split = source.Split(New Char() {"1"c, "2"c, "3"c, "4"c, "5"c, "6"c, "7"c, "8"c, "9"c, "0"c})

    For i = 0 To split.GetUpperBound(0)
        If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(split(i)) Then
            Continue For
        End If
        Console.WriteLine("{0}. {1}", i, split(i).Trim("."c, " "c))
    Next
```

Note that this breaks if there are more than 9 items (10 if you include `0`). Actually there are lots of ways to break this, but none of them fall within the specification.

Comment: You could use `"0123456789".ToCharArray` for brevity and obviousness ;)